# Angular 2 universal http request

Tags: angular, typescript, xmlhttprequest, switch-statement

I am looking for an universal http request for angular, like in vanilla JS, where you can give the request method as an input parameter ('POST', 'GET'...).

I tried with switch case but it's not working very well.

```
Request(UserDetails, endpoint, method): Observable<Comment[]> {
        const bodyString = UserDetails;
        const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        const options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
        const meth = method
        console.log(meth)
        let request;

        switch(meth) {
            case 'post': {
                request = this.http.post;
                console.log(request)        
                break;
            }
            case 'get': {
                request = this.http.post;
                break;
            }
            case 'patch': {
                request = this.http.patch;
                break;
            }
            case 'delete': {
                request = this.http.delete;
                break;
            }
        };
        return request(endpoint, bodyString, options)
            .map((res: Response) => res.json())
            .catch((error: any) =>  Observable.throw(error.json() || 'server 
error'));
    }
```

Comment: need more chars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `http.request` method:

```
Request(UserDetails, endpoint, method): Observable<Comment[]> {
    const bodyString = UserDetails;
    const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    //const options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
    const request = new Request({method: method,
                                 headers: headers
                               });

    return this.http.request(request, bodyString)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .catch((error: any) =>  Observable.throw(error.json() || 'serveerror'));
}
```

For more information, see [Angular API Reference - http.request](https://angular.io/api/http/Http#request)

Comment: Thanks, but it!s still not working. it got this message: `argument of type '{method: any; headers: any }' s not assignable to parameter of type 'Request Args'`

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the parameters as well:

```
switch(meth) {
            case 'post': {
                request = this.http.post(endpoint, bodyString, options);   
                break;
            }
            case 'get': {
                request = this.http.post(endpoint, bodyString, options);
                break;
            }
        return request
            .map((res: Response) => res.json())
            .catch((error: any) =>  Observable.throw(error.json() || 'server error'));
```

Comment: but I'm still looking for a more elegant solution :)

Comment: He just wants a reference to it, it's being invoked later in the return promise.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
// Make sure to validate acceptable values
const meth = "post";

request = this.http[meth]( ...args );
```

This is object bracket notation to access properties dynamically